# libxml constants are accessible, yet don't register as defined constants

Tags: php, constants, libxml2

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php), there are a number of constants defined when the libxml extension is enabled.

These are accessible in the code, so something like

```
var_dump(LIBXML_DTDLOAD);
```

will return a value of `int(4)` (no problem so far, that's exactly what I expect to see)

What puzzles me is if I do

```
echo var_dump(defined(LIBXML_DTDLOAD));
```

I get a `bool(false)` returned....

So how can I access the constant and see its value if it isn't (apparently) defined? Or why does `defined()` return a false for a constant that clearly is defined?

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/saMS9)

Comment: You didn't quote the constant name^^

Comment: <facepalm />Feeling stupid :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't quote the constant name

```
var_dump(defined('LIBXML_DTDLOAD')); // bool(true)
```